# Decompiling 8051 binary, read from EEPROM

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, decompiling, 8051

I'm trying to decompile the firmware of a Logitech Freedom 2.4 Cordless Joystick. I've managed to get something of the EEPROM. ([here](https://filebin.net/kxht1rruvvph6www/LogitechFreedom2.4CordlessJoystick.rom?t=2sqw9uv2))
The EEPROM that is used is the Microchip 25AA320, which is a 32Kbit SPI-EEPROM. The MCU is a nRF24E1G , that contains a 8051 MCU. 
The ROM should be 4096 bytes, so I think that my reading program looped over it self 4 times.
I managed to extract a 4kB ROM ([here](https://filebin.net/kxht1rruvvph6www/dump.rom?t=6eph4wap)), but the start of the file doesn't look clean.

I loaded both files into IDA Pro and Ghidra and selected the 8051 processor. They don't generate anything useful.

Could anyone help me decompiling this ROM?

I used [this](https://pastebin.com/iRjVd1jF) Arduino Sketch to dump the rom.
Together with this python script

```
## Author: Arpan Das
## Date:   Fri Jan 11 12:16:59 2019 +0530
## URL: https://github.com/Cyberster/SPI-Based-EEPROM-Reader-Writer

## It listens to serial port and writes contents into a file
## requires pySerial to be installed 
import sys 
import serial
import time
start = time.time()

MEMORY_SIZE = 4096 # In bytes
serial_port = 'COM5'
baud_rate = 115200 # In arduino, Serial.begin(baud_rate)
write_to_file_path = "dump.rom"

output_file = open(write_to_file_path, "wb")
ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)

print("Press d for dump ROM else CTRL+C to exit.")
ch = sys.stdin.read(1)

if ch == 'd':
    ser.write('d')
    for i in range(MEMORY_SIZE/32): # i.e. MEMORY_SIZE / 32
        # wait until arduino response with 'W' i.e. 1 byte of data write request
        while (ser.read() != 'W'): continue
        ser.write('G') # sends back write request granted signal

        for j in range(32):
            byte = ser.read(1);
            output_file.write(byte);

        print(str(MEMORY_SIZE - (i * 32)) + " bytes remaining.")

print '\nIt took', time.time()-start, ' seconds.'
```

Comment: Did you read the chapter in the data sheet about the organization of the EEPROM?

Comment: Oh, and please check which 4K-pages of your 16K dump are correct. It seems that the first bytes are wrong.

Comment: @thebusybee I did check it. I haven't got a clue what characteristics correspond to which piece of code (I've added the Arduino code I used to dump the EEPROM to the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did, the next part left is for you. My machine is a Win10 notebook, however I used unix tools because they are so capable.

First of all, I divided the 16KB dump into four 4KB parts. The first one was different from the other three. And the provided 4KB dump is different to all of these parts. I did not investigate this further, and simply took one of the other three parts that are all equal.

```
$ split -b 4K LogitechFreedom2.4CordlessJoystick.rom part
$ cmp partaa partab
partaa partab differ: byte 1, line 1
$ cmp partab partac
$ cmp partac partad
$ cmp dump.rom partaa
dump.rom partaa differ: byte 9, line 1
$ cmp dump.rom partab
dump.rom partab differ: byte 1, line 1
```

From the microcontroller's data sheet I learned that the EEPROM contents has a header of at least 3 bytes (chapter 10.2 at page 61).

These bytes are:

```
0b   Version = 00, Reserved = 00, SPEED = 0.5MHz, XO_FREQ = 16MHz
03   Offset to start of user program = 3
0f   Number of 256 bytes block = 15
```

The last entry seems to be off by one, because there seems to be code in the 16th block, too.

Anyway, these bytes look decent, so I cut the first 3 bytes.

```
$ dd if=partad of=rom.bin bs=1 skip=3
4093+0 records in
4093+0 records out
4093 bytes (4,1 kB, 4,0 KiB) copied, 0,0270132 s, 152 kB/s
$ dd if=partad of=head.bin bs=1 count=3
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
3 bytes copied, 0,0043809 s, 0,7 kB/s
$ od -Ax -t x1 rom.bin > rom.hex
$ od -Ax -t x1 head.bin > head.hex
```

The hex files are nice for loading them into an editor and look around.

I loaded the remaining 4093 bytes into a disassembler I once wrote and peeked around a bit. It looks promising, so I think you can go on without me now:

```
C0000:  ljmp    C0F54

C0003:  setb    021H.2
        reti

C000B:  xch     a,r5
        inc     r6
        xrl     a,r6
        mov     a,#0B2H
        movc    a,@a+pc
        movx    @r1,a
        mov     r7,a
        setb    021H.2
        reti

C0F54:  mov     psw,#000H
        mov     sp,#07BH
        mov     r0,#0FFH
        mov     @r0,#000H
        djnz    r0,C0F5C
        ljmp    C0C09
```

Comment: Massive thank you! I suppose you just selected the 8051 instruction set in the disassembler? If yes, which disassembler did you use Ghidra or IDA?

Comment: None of Ghidra or IDA. I did not know about Ghidra until I saw your post, and IDA is non-free software. I prefer FOSS. ;-) Actually I used a disassembler I wrote around 1999, but it's primitive compared to current software.

Comment: That's good to know! I am using Ghidra right now, but I need to look into defining a custom instruction set, since the MCU is a mix of 8051 instructions and is not fully compatible with the Intel 8051